# Java to Postgresql Connectivity error - unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: postgresql, ssl, jdbc, ssl-certificate, hikaricp

I am unable to connect to postgresql DB and I get the below error:

*Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: SSL error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at org.postgresql.ssl.MakeSSL.convert(MakeSSL.java:43) ~[postgresql-42.3.8.jar:42.3.8]
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.enableSSL(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:571) ~[postgresql-42.3.8.jar:42.3.8]
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:168) ~[postgresql-42.3.8.jar:42.3.8]
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:235) ~[postgresql-42.3.8.jar:42.3.8]
at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.3.8.jar:42.3.8]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.(PgConnection.java:223) ~[postgresql-42.3.8.jar:42.3.8]
at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:402) ~[postgresql-42.3.8.jar:42.3.8]
at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:261) ~[postgresql-42.3.8.jar:42.3.8]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
... 120 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:370) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:313) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:308) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:652) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:367) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:376) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:479) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:457) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:200) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:155) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1320) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1233) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:417) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:389) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
at org.postgresql.ssl.MakeSSL.convert(MakeSSL.java:41) ~[postgresql-42.3.8.jar:42.3.8]
... 132 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:271) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:312) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:221) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:128) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:636) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
... 144 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
... 150 common frames omitted*

I am using a custom trust store and not a default java trust store. I can see entries in my custom store:
*Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN
Your keystore contains 1 entry*

I tried connecting to the same DB, by writing the certificate contents to a file and passing it in jdbc url like this and this is working fine.
`sslmode=verify-ca&sslrootcert=<path-of-cert>`

Not sure what is missing. Can someone please guide me here.